# Maven multimodule build. I want to deploy the ear to our Repository, but not the other modules

Tags: maven, deployment, module

We have multi-module project that consists of 17 modules. There'a base jar module. There are 15 *filter jar* modules that depend upon that base jar. Then, there's the Ear that we build that contains the 16 other jars.

We have the build working just fine, but we'd like to deploy our Ear to our Maven repository -- mainly because it'll make it easy for our deployment tools to get to it. Plus, we can easily do that via `mvn deploy` without having to put together another tool.

The problem is that when we say `mvn deploy`, we deploy the Ear and the 16 other jars. Those jars are not used in any other project, and we simply don't want them clogging up our Maven repository.

Is there a way to specify that a particular module doesn't get put into the Maven repository when I say `mvn deploy`?

Comment: `mvn clean deploy -pl our-ear-module`?

Comment: You could define `<skip>true</skip>` related to maven-deploy-plugin in each of the modules you don't like to deploy to repository but I don't recommend it. Furthermore the only thing you are waisting is a little bit hard drive space...for releases for snapshot you should have configured a cleanup setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the documentation, I found the `${maven.skip.deploy}` property. I actually set this to `true` in the parent project, then set it to false in the EAR build. That does what I want, deploys only the EAR. This way, if another module is added, it will by default not be deployed.

[steve c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897870/steve-c) recommended `mvn -pl core-ear clean deploy` which doesn't work in my circumstance. The module I want to deploy is actually a module of a module, so the main level build doesn't see it.

Our structure is like this:

```
parent --|
         |-engine
         |-filter1
         |-filter2
         .
         .
         |-distribution --|
                          |--jar
                          |--sar
                          |--ear  <-Deploying this one only
```

[khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) mentioned setting `<skip>true</skip>` in all of the modules except for the one I want to deploy. khmarbaise recommends against this, and I don't blame him. However, there are several issues here. First, we're doing [continuous delivery](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/continuousdeliverymaven.php) which means that we will have a new version in our repository for each build. I also want to make sure no one tries to depend upon these jars.

I set the property `${maven.deploy.skip}` to `false` in my parent module. This means it's that way in all of my modules and none of them will deploy. I don't need to configure my `maven-deploy-plugin` in order to set this.

I then set `${maven.deploy.skip}` to `true` in the only module I actually want to deploy (which is the ear module of the distribution submodule). Running `mvn clean deploy` from the parent now only deploys the ear distribution module I actually want to deploy.